# Replacing only variables in specific locations with Replace All

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

Suppose I have an example expression defined like this:

`line = R0*f[R0,x] + R0^2*42*D[g[R0,x],x]`

I would like to replace `R0` with `r`, but *only* in the arguments of functions.

In this example I would like to use a replacement rule  `line /. { ??? }`  in order to obtain

`R0*f[r,x] + R0^2*42*D[g[r,x],x]`

What replacement rule `???` do I need to use here?

In my case, `line` is hundreds of terms long and it would be very cumbersome to not automate this. (If it helps, all functions always take the same list of arguments.)

Comment: By "functions" do you mean "user-defined functions"?

Comment: If you have a list of the relevant functions, it might be easier to work from that direction. For example, you might add DownValues directly to (for example) f & g that handle `R0`. Or you might build a helper function, say `CleanR0` that replaces `f[R0,...]` with `f[r,...]` (and similarly with all relevant functions).

Comment: @lericr Yes, the functions are user defined, but it is a long list and I would prefer not having to think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]   
line = R0*f[R0, x] + R0^2*42*D[g[R0, x], x]
line /. {p_Symbol[R0, a_] /; Context[p] == "Global`" -> p[r, a], 
  Derivative[k__][p_Symbol][R0, b_] /; Context[p] == "Global`" -> 
   Derivative[k][p][r, b]}
```

$$\text{R0} f(r,x)+42 \text{R0}^2 g^{(0,1)}(r,x)$$

Comment: This gives warning/message. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2cg5.png)  V 13.1. What is the purpose for checking that context is global in your method?

Comment: Add parentheses, i.e., `line /. {(p_[R0, a_] /; Context[p]) == "Global`" :> p[r, a], Derivative[k__][p_][R0, b_] /; Context[p] == "Global`" -> Derivative[k][p][r, b]}`

Comment: @Nasser, I used context "Global\`" since `Context[Times]` and for  other built-in functions is "System\`" and this way I can avoid conversions in other parts. May be there is a more elegant way to do this. The messages box was in the background so I didn't see it, although it computed. Thanks to Bob Hanlon for the correction.

Comment: @Syed Thank you, that is perfect! The trick with ```Context``` is great, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
line = R0*f[R0, x] + R0^2*42*D[g[R0, x], x];
MyFunctions = {f, g, Derivative[0, 1][g]};
Clean[fn_][R0, args___] := fn[r, args];
line /. {fn : Alternatives @@ MyFunctions :> Clean[fn]}
```

This assumes that R0 will have no OwnValues. Also, you might be able to automate the generation of `MyFunctions` if there will be several different patterns of derivatives (or other functions).

The following uses Syed's idea for checking the context, and it generalizes a bit (you could build out that generalization further).

```
line = R0*f[R0, x] + R0^2*42*D[g[R0, x], x];
R0 /: Derivative[params___][fun_Symbol][R0, args___] := 
Derivative[params][fun][r, args] /; Context[f] == "Global`";
R0 /: f_Symbol[R0, args___] := f[r, args] /; Context[f] == "Global`";
line
```

This assumes that you don't need the original form with the explicit `R0`s, because the up values for `R0` will be applied automatically.

Comment: Thanks, it is a very nice solution, I just find the other one a bit more practical because I do not need to define ```MyFunctions```. The generalization looks great though! (Although it has the drawback of influencing my entire notebook globally.)